# Proof for positivity of solutions of an ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, population-dynamics, epidemiology

I have an ODE system  that takes a mathematical model describing the dynamics between HCV and the immune system. My question is about the proof that the solution of the ODE system is positive if the initial conditions are all positive. I tried this proof:

Consider the DE
x˙=f(x).
The vector function f is said to be essentially nonnegative if for all i=1,…,n, fi(X)≥0, where X∈Rn≥0 such that Xi=0, where Xi denotes the i-th element of X.

So for my system:

ẋ = λ − dx − βvx

ẏ = βvx − ay − pyz

v̇ = ky − uv − qvw

ẇ = gvw − hw

ż = cyz − bz

I have an issue with proving that, the r.h.s. of y˙ for y=0 is βvx, is non-negative for all v.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You need that $\dot X_i\ge 0$ whenever $X_i=0$. This is easily checked as true for this system. $βvx$ has all factors non-negative.

Comment: @LutzLehmann for beta and x which are both non-negative its true, but how is it the case for v since we don't really whether its positive or not for now. if you wouldn't mind clarifying this, or maybe its something I didn't understand in the theorem.

Comment: So you have to check that $f_i\geq 0$ whenever $X_i=0$. If $\beta, \lambda, k \geq 0$, then that's completely obvious, unless there is something I do not understand. For $\dot{y}$ you mention for example, well $\beta v y\geq 0$ since the three factors are each greater or equal to zero. For $\dot{x}$, you just need $\lambda\geq 0$.

Comment: You only consider points in the positive orthant and its boundary, that is, $X\ge 0$, and test that the direction of the vector field keeps the system there in forward time. For inner points this is trivial, so it remains to test the boundary planes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the theorem written in details in Section 3 of that [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.868.7534&rep=rep1&type=pdf). According to Theorem in that [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.868.7534&rep=rep1&type=pdf), if we have a dynamical system of the form
$$
\dot{\bf{X}}={\bf{f(X)}},\;\;{\bf{X}}\in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
then we need to check that $f_i\geq 0$ if $X_i=0$ for all $i=1,2...,n$.

In your case, we have
$$
{\bf{X}}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\y\\v\\w\\z
\end{array}
\right),
$$
and ${\bf{f(X)}}$ given by the RHS of the system given in the question.

Then we compute:
$$
f_1(0,y,v,w)=\lambda,\;\;f_2(x,0,v,w,z)=\beta v x,\;\;f_3(x,y,0,w,z)=k y,\\f_4(x,y,v,0,z)=0,\;\;f_5(x,y,v,w,0)=0.
$$
If the constants $\lambda, \beta,$ and $k$ are assumed to be greater or equal to zero (nonnegative), then it is easy to check that all the expressions above are nonnegative if the variables in the expressions are themselves are nonnegative.

Thus ${\bf{f(X)}}$ is essentially nonnegative and according to Theorem 3.1 of that [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.868.7534&rep=rep1&type=pdf), we have that the solution components of the ODE system are greater or equal to zero if the initial conditions are all greater or equal to zero.

Comment: The parameters lambda, beta and k are indeed all positive. I have simply not read properly the theorem since it requires to check fi≥0 where X∈Rn≥0 such that Xi=0. So my issue with the v is cleared with the "X∈Rn≥0"

Comment: Can you "approve" my answer then, please?